# how to open a firefox browser through selenium 3.6.0 with another profile using Javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, firefoxdriver

I want to launch the Firefox browser through selenium-webdriver 3.6.0 with some of the default settings of the browser changed. Specifically, I want Firefox to download files, during automated testing, without prompting whether to save or not and to download to a predefined directory other than the default, which is the downloads folder.

The way to do it on google chrome is this:

```
if (this.bName === 'chrome') {  
   var cap = Capabilities.chrome();  
   var options = {  
      'prefs': {  
          profile: {  
            default_content_settings: {  
                  popups: 0,  
            },  
          },  
          download: {  
            default_directory: path.join(__dirname,  
 '/../Downloads For Testing'),  
          }  
      }  
 };  
 var cap = cap.set('chromeOptions', options);  
 this.browser = new Builder().withCapabilities(cap).build();  
}
```

A relevant try on Firefox, by setting the preferences after creating a new profile, didn't work.

I include the Profile from Firefox folder

> firefoxProfile = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox').Profile;

and I build with new capabilities

```
else if (this.bName === 'firefox') {
            var cap = Capabilities.firefox();
            var profile = new firefoxProfile;
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path.join(__dirname, '/../Downloads For Testing'));
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/html");
            cap.set('firefox_profile', profile);
            console.log(profile);
            this.browser = new Builder().withCapabilities(cap).build();
        }
```

This is the printout of the new profile object:

```
Profile {
  preferences_:
   { 'browser.download.folderList': 2,
     'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false,
     'browser.download.dir': 'C:\\path\\Downloads For Testing',
     'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'text/html' },
  template_: undefined,
  extensions_: []
}
```

The browser is initiated with no errors and all promises are returned correctly by mocha, the test framework, until pressing the button to download a file and the normal dialog shows up, so no success.

Comment: Please check the paragraph "Notes for Selenium-webdriver package users" on https://www.npmjs.com/package/firefox-profile. 
Links don't work.. It doesn't say which v of Selenium. Have tried the package without "addExtension" wraparound,  just 
            "myProfile.updatePreferences();" before calling encode. Doesn't call anything inside encode func. No errors

Answer (score 1):

The index.js file in `selenium-webdriver\firefox` states clearly how to create a new profile dynamically and set the preferences.

```
* The {@linkplain Profile} class may be used to configure the browser profile
* used with WebDriver, with functions to install additional
* {@linkplain Profile#addExtension extensions}, configure browser
* {@linkplain Profile#setPreference preferences}, and more. For example, you
* may wish to include Firebug:
*
*     const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
*     const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
*
*     let profile = new firefox.Profile();
*     profile.addExtension('/path/to/firebug.xpi');
*     profile.setPreference('extensions.firebug.showChromeErrors', true);
*
*     let options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile); 
*     let driver = new Builder()
*         .forBrowser('firefox')
*         .setFirefoxOptions(options)
*         .build();
```

It tried it and it didn't work. Obviously I didn't try to add the extension but only to set the 4 preferences written in my question.

What did the trick for me, as a workaround though, was to create a new profile by executing `firefox.exe -p` on the Windows' Run dialog. (Press the Windows icon key and R on keyboard to get the run dialog) 
After that, I used this new "testing" profile as a template to create a new temporary one dynamically through Selenium.

```
var profile = new firefox.Profile('/pathTo/firefox profile for testing/');
```

And here is the trick. It appears to be a thing with Firefox and MIME types. If the server, sending the file to download, names the file's content-type differently as the Firefox would, the auto save won't happen and the 'save or open file' dialog will appear.  
Probably for security reasons. 
 [The content type can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355204/how-to-handle-download-pop-up-in-firefox-while-downloading-excel-using-selenium)

In my case it's about a CSV file and setting `profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")` while the server sends a content-type of text/html and firefox identifies it as TXT file didn't work. 
So I edited the handlers.json file inside `/pathTo/firefox profile for testing/` by setting the attribute 'ask' of 'text/plain' inside 'mimeTypes' from true to false.

And of course I set as an only preference the path for the file to get downloaded to. BTW this will also create the path, at least the last folder. So my code is:

```
    else if (this.bName === 'firefox') {
        var cap = Capabilities.firefox();
        var profile = new firefox.Profile('/pathTo/firefox profile for testing/');
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", '/pathTo/Downloads For Testing');
        let options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
        this.browser = new Builder().forBrowser(this.bName).setFirefoxOptions(options).build();
    }
```

[You can also try this and not mess with the handler.json (end of page)](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2430485) but didn't work for me.

[Or just go brute force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839544/using-selenium-webdrivers-method-browser-helperapps-neverask-savetodisk-how-ca), this didn't either.